# Criteria expression on ArrayCollection is case sensitive

Tags: symfony, doctrine, criteria

I have an ArrayCollection from Hashtag entity (database/table collation both set to utf8_bin_ci) which I want to match on a Criteria but it's **not case insensitive**.

I've tried 'contains', 'eq', 'startsWith', 'endsWith' expressions, but it returns null on matching, however it has many results without the Criteria matching.

If I add strtolower / strtoupper to `$this->name` property, it works in the specified case.

*How can I make it case-insensitive the Criteria or the matching here?*

```
  public function getHashtags($max = null) {
    $hashtags = $this->hashtags;
    $hashtags->getIterator();
    $crit = Criteria::create()
                    ->where(Criteria::expr()->contains('name', $this->name))
    if (!empty($max)) {
      $crit->setMaxResults($max);
    }

    return $hashtags->matching($crit);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code calls [`getIterator()`](http://I%20would%20assume,%20that%20%60$hashtags-%3EgetIterator()%60%20will%20prevent%20any%20database%20magic%20from%20ever%20happening,%20because%20it%20initializes%20the%20collection(see:%20https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/7e6599ffdc7287f6732e05af534f873a971a554d/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/AbstractLazyCollection.php#L281)), which will prevent any database magic from ever happening, because it initializes the collection (which loads all entries), so your collation doesn't matter anyway.

Also, the [`contains`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/7e6599ffdc7287f6732e05af534f873a971a554d/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Expr/ClosureExpressionVisitor.php#L156) function uses `strpos`, which obviously is not case-insensitive.

Since your code already pulls in all hashtags, just filter it already:

```
$hashtags = array_filter(function(Hashtag $hashtag) {
    return stripos($this->name, $hashtag->getName());
}, $this->hashtags);
if(!empty($max)) {
    $hashtags = array_slice($hashtags, 0, $max, true); 
    // remove true, if you don't care about keys  ^, this preserves them
}
return $hashtags;
```

Comment: thank you, you're right basically, however the code needed a lil fix

Comment: fair enough, I thought the field was fix. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

regard to @Jakumi correct answer:

```
$hashtags = array_filter($this->hashtags->toArray(), function (TwitterHashtag $hashtag) use ($fields) {
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (false !== stripos($hashtag->getName(), $this->$field)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
});
if (!empty($max)) {
  $hashtags = array_slice($hashtags, 0, $max, false);
}
```